# MongoDB: Group values in nested array to get count

Tags: arrays, mongodb, nested

I've searched but could not find an answer to my problem.
I've got a collection with this sample structure in MongoDB:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectID(1),
  "Manual_Tags": [
    {
      _source: {
        tags: [ "tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
        other_values: ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
{
  "_id": ObjectID(2),
  "Manual_Tags": [
    {
      _source: {
        tags: [ "tag2", "tag3", "tag4"]
        other_values: ...
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to know the count of instances for each value of "tags" existing in the collection for all documents (Manual_Tags[]._source.tags[]). That is, for the 2 documents in the sample above, the listing would be:
tag1: 1
tag2: 2
tag3: 2
tag4: 1

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) queries. First you need to unwind both the arrays and then just group on tags to get the count

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$unwind: '$Manual_Tags'},
  {$unwind: '$Manual_Tags._source.tags'},
  {$group: {_id: '$Manual_Tags._source.tags', count:{$sum:1}}}
)
```

Comment: Thank you. That simple query did it.

Comment: Hello @sidgate, It is working fine, but here I need to add limit with highest count first. Can you please help me out. For an instance, my result is : { "_id" : "Platterz.co", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "ChowNow", "count" : 3 }
{ "_id" : "cater2.me", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "App-App.co", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "airportsherpa.io", "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "Eat24", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "Chowbus", "count" : 5 }

But I want Like:  { "_id" : "Chowbus", "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : "Eat24", "count" : 4 }
{ "_id" : "ChowNow", "count" : 3 }

Answer (score 1):

Using Projections and Groups

```
db.mycollection.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: {
                _id:0,
                tag_count:{$size:"$Manual_Tags._source.tags"},
            }
        }, 
        {
            $group: {
                tag_total:{$sum:"$tag_count"},
            }
        }
    ]
)
```